# What is the significance of the direwolf deaths? Is there a hidden meaning?

Tags: analysis, game-of-thrones

In Season 1 of *Game of Thrones*, we saw six direwolf cubs. They match exactly to the Stark children in terms of gender and the one outcast (Jon Snow and Ghost).

In five episodes of season 6, we have seen two of the direwolves die; only two of them are left.

Is there any hidden meaning behind the death or is it pointing towards the end of the Starks being near?

Comment: At this point it seems primarily opinion-based, although we _might_ find out in the future.

Comment: GRRM is known to break high fantasy tropes... he introduced "An item of power" which normally means a person will be the victor and survive, but then thoroughly shows you the that item really meant nothing.

Answer (score 12):

I think Summer's death especially is significant in the way that she's one of Bran's protectors and died along with the other, Hodor.

As for the other direwolves, Lady's death has much parallels to Sansa's life. Lady dies in place of Nymeria, her destiny is decided for her by others and she is innocent. That's the same as what happens to Sansa after her father dies and before she joins Jon at the Wall.

Nymeria like Arya is running around lost and isolated from the rest of her family. Grey Wind met the same end as Robb and as far as Shaggydog is concerned if he's dead (I hope he's not) he's been betrayed like Rickon.

So each death alone has significance to the person who owned the direwolf but I don't think they are connected or their deaths forshadow what will happen to the Stark family.

Comment: This pretty much sums up my thoughts on this as well.  Though, interestingly, I don't know that Ghost's story really matches Jon Snow's in the same way - or at least I'm unable to draw the same parallel.

Comment: @JesseWilliams only thing I could think of would be that Ghost is a loner and outcast as is Jon as a bastard and a 'traitor' . He's also remarkably quiet for a dire wolf.

Comment: @JesseWilliams If i remember correctly, Ghost is given to Jon Snow because he is an albino, the runt of the litter. Quoting Game of Thrones Wikia : "Jon Snow finds an albino direwolf pup, the runt of the litter. Theon Greyjoy mockingly acknowledges that the wolf is like Snow."